# How does COUNT(*) know what it is counting in these examples?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently learning SQL and  I am confused on how COUNT(*) knows what to count. I've gone through a lot of google and this site and on here but I'm still confused. I understand that it will not show any null values, but how is it calculating what I want it to? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio (Express edition).

For example, in my current database I made, I made this query:

```
SELECT teamName, teamCity, teamManager, COUNT(*) AS [Number of Awards Won]
FROM team INNER JOIN athlete ON team.teamId = athlete.teamId
          INNER JOIN winner ON athlete.athleteId = winner.athleteId
GROUP BY teamName, teamCity, teamManager
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

(This query is answering the question of "Which teams have won 4 or more awards among all its listed athletes?")

Now, it works exactly how it should...but what is it looking at to get this answer? I don't understand how it is calculating this.

Here is one more example from another database I was given by my teacher:

```
SELECT devName, COUNT(*) AS [Number of Players]
FROM developer INNER JOIN game ON developer.devId = game.devId
        INNER JOIN record   ON game.gameId = record.gameId 
            INNER JOIN player   ON record.playerId = player.playerId
GROUP BY devName;
```

(This query answers the question of "How many players are playing games per developer?")

I am able to make these query's I just do not understand how COUNT works, because sometimes I am just guessing but it ends up working. I'd like to know where I should be focusing on in this case.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This is covered in the manual: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql>. _"`*`
Specifies that `COUNT` should count all rows to determine the total table row count to return..."_

Comment: `COUNT(*)` Counts all the records in the table but where as `COUNT(Column Name)` Counts only the `Not NULL` Rows in the table

Comment: SQL statements are not executed in top down order - count will occur after all filters are applied (ie ON clauses and WHERE conditions)

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry I am so stuck on this still, so in the first example in my post it's because of the ON clauses? I just can't see how it is making it do that still

Comment: The manual wording is 'An aggregate function performs a calculation on a set of values,' -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 the set of values in this case is the data returned by the from and join clauses. You should research sql order of operations.

Comment: The same link also says 'Except for COUNT(*), aggregate functions ignore null values.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COUNT` function is an aggregate function that returns the exact number of rows returned by a query. In your case, you're grouping your results by some column, so the function counts the "starting" number of records for each returned row.